# Left join mysql multi table id and display the name in JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json, angularjs

I'm a new in `angularjs` and `json`. I want to display the attribute `name` from `id` from one table (table A) that have relation to other table (table B) that contains `id` from table A.

here's table A:

```
---------------------
id_skill | name_skill
---------------------
1        | medical record
2        | rontgen
3        | thorax
---------------------
```

and table B:

```
----------------------------------------
id_client | name_client | skill_client
----------------------------------------
1         | john        | 1,2
2         | smith       | 3
----------------------------------------
```

I want echoing/displaying data from table B, but in the `skill_client` column contains `id(s)` from table A. I want to display that column with `name_skill` from table A in `json` method and `PHP`.

so that I can get data in my page like this :

```
------------------------
Name       |    Skills
------------------------
John       | medical record, rontgen
Smith      | thorax
------------------------
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really change the table structure and normalize your database. The best thing would be to create a new table to store the `id_client` and `id_skill` and remove the comma separated data from the 2nd table. However in your case you can try something as

```
select 
b.name_client, 
group_concat(a.name_skill) as skills 
from tableb b 
left join tablea a on find_in_set(a.id_skill,b.skill_client) > 0 
group by b.id_client ;
```

Comment: yes, I think I should normalize my db, I have to create a new table that store id_client and id_skill. Thanks for the answer

Comment: by the way, can you explain to me how I can join three tables (query)so that I can get name_skill in my client page? @Abhik Chakraborty

Comment: Perhaps add a new question with all the details. The answer is pretty simple.

Comment: Well. I want to fetch table B (client data) so I can get name and skills, but in skills column I want echoing name_skill not id_skill and split by comma(s), implode in PHP. Can you explain please?

Comment: if you had a 3rd table as  I explained the query would be `select b.name_client,group_concat(a.name_skill) as skills from tablec c join tablea a on a.id_skill = c.id_skill join table b on b.id_client = c.id_client group by b.id_client`

Comment: can you help me again, see at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28822926/query-to-display-column-data-row-group-by-data-value-in-json-from-php

Answer (score 0):

Use explode(',', $myString);

```
$myArray = explode(',', $myString);
```

This get an array of Strings from a String.

if string is: **"medical record, rontgen"** 
then you get a array whit lenght two:

*$myArray[0]= "medical record"*

*$myArray[1]= "rontgen"*

Then your use json_encode($yourData) to convert vars u objects in json string.

Comment: thanks for your answer but I think I have to create a new table, it's too complex to me because I'm new in json and angularjs, but thanks anyway